# Bootstrap4 - how to make cards within nested row stretch to match next row?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Trying to wrap some cards into a rather complex layout. The elements on the right side, namely the cards.

What I have so far
https://jsfiddle.net/shifterofbits/ojgtmn80/5/

In the screenshot mockup and fiddle, the "box 2 and box 3" components look like this

```
 <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="card"  style="height:235px">
            <div class="card-header">
                box 2
            </div>          
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">Title 2</h3>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="card"  style="height:235px">
            <div class="card-header">
                box 3
            </div>          
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">Title here</h3>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>      
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Here is a mockup of the type of layout im trying to get to.
Notice the right side, everything is aligned.
[image]

Comment: I think this layout could be made much easier using CSS grid, any particular reason you want to use the `card` component from Bootstrap specifically?

Comment: I like the card-header feature

Comment: Just in case, see this, you could just add the header and it will look the same: https://codepen.io/IvanS95/pen/REaGar

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't even aware of grid features of CSS.

Comment: Yeah, its pretty powerful to work with, and since its native you can take a lot of advantage from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

box 2   Title 2 With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.  Go somewhere       box 3   Title here With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.  Go somewhere

Comment: Add a col-md-12 in the an div inserted in the row class for proper positioning

Comment: It was your comment suggestion that I was able to use, but I marked this as the answer.  I updated the fiddle also.  Thanks